# Errors when passing bash variable in osascript

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ssh, osascript

Using osascript, I'm able to tell the Terminal application to open an ssh connection in a separate terminal window, however, I run into errors when trying to pass bash variables in the script.

This script works just fine:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "ssh user@hostname -p port -L 9999:localhost:80 -i keyfile"
end tell'
...more commands...
```

But running a script like this one...

```
read -p "Port: " prt
read -p "Localhost port: " lhprt
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
            do script "ssh user@hostname -p \"$prt\" -L \"$lhprt\":localhost:80 -i keyfile"
        end tell'
...more commands...
```

It doesn't pass the variables, i.e. the command passed in the new terminal window is

```
ssh user@hostname -p "$prt"
```

How might I format this to make it so my bash variables get fed through?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score -1):

Just invert the quote type 
Using single quote is preventing the shell to expand your parameters

Edit:
You can close the string just around your variables too.
I.e. 
'this is a '$variable' in a "string".'

Comment: Can you give an example? I have multiple nested quotes, so I'm not certain which to switch. Right now, switching them, I'm getting
'syntax error: Expected expression, property or key form, etc. but found unknown token. (-2741)'